# Removing text block between two tags in file regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm creating a digital signage application in c# and having trouble removing a block of text between 2 sections. The text I would like to remove is between [Video] and [Video_END]

I've been trying to use regex to achieve this after viewing other examples however I get a compiler error:

**CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(string, string, string, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions)**' **has some invalid arguments**

Here is my code:
  StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();

```
    string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Intranet\Net\ProjectApollo\Screens\"+location);

var output = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=\[VIDEO\]).*(?=\[VIDEO_END\])", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

I am working from an example and changed the 2 tags to [VIDEO] and [VIDEO_END]

I managed to get past the compiler error by doing this:

> var output = Regex.Replace(file.ToString(), @"(?<=[VIDEO]).*(?=[VIDEO_END])", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);

```
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Intranet\Net\ProjectApollo\Screens\" + location, output);
```

However when I look at the file, its deleted all the contents of the file.

I have tried this:

> string text = text.ReadAllText(@"C:\Intranet\Net\ProjectApollo\Screens\"+location);

and then

> var output = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?s)(?<=[VIDEO]).*(?=[VIDEO_END])", "");
>
> text.WriteAllText(@"C:\Intranet\Net\ProjectApollo\Screens\" + location, output);

the file says it has changed but looking at it, the content between VIDEO and VIDEO_END is still there.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Your [code works fine](https://ideone.com/MplfD7). However, the regex you should consider using is `(?s)(?<=\[VIDEO\]).*?(?=\[VIDEO_END\])` and remove `RegexOptions.Multiline`

Comment: I honestly can't find anything wrong. Is **file** a string? It must be a string. I *think* you're passing a file object or something like that.

Comment: Could you provide an [MRE]? Could you tell us the type of `file` variable? `Console.WriteLine("file: Type is {0}", file.GetType());` and past the result.

Comment: Please show all the relevant code. `file`, what is the variable type? It must be `string`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `string[] file` to the `Regex.Replace`. Instead, you should iterate `string[] file` (perhaps `string[] lines` is better name) and process it line by line.

```
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines ...

file.Select(line=>Regex.Replace(line,...))
```

Comment: yeah, you are right, thanks

Comment: Or TS could use ReadAllText instead. Like `string file = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Intranet\Net\ProjectApollo\Screens\"+location);`. I'm guessing that was the intention since `RegexOptions.Multiline` is specified and it doesn't mean anything on a single line match. (Not that it matters with the regex in question ;)

Comment: I'll give this a try

Comment: Turns out that the only thing i need to change to remove the video from the slider is to replace this value: data-ytid="youtubevid" to data-ytid="". Although I would like to know how to remove a whole block of text if possible.